# Strange database schema - is it many-to-many?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have a strange database schema and can't decide if it's many-to-many or something else.

I have this three tables:

### Table 1: Programs (retrieved by API)

```
id
api_id
api_program_name
...
```

---

### Table 2: Program_Conditions (also retrieved by API)

```
id
program_id
program_conditions_group_id
api_id
description
reward
...
```

---

### Table 3: Program_Conditions_Groups

```
id
reward
description
```

---

Well, you normally would think that the Program_Conditions is the pivot table and Programs as well as Program_Conditions_Groups are many-to-many to each other. 
The problem is that Programs can have many entries in Program_Conditions_Groups but Program_Conditions_Groups can only belong to one Program.

The purpose is that Program_Conditions_Groups groups all entries from Program_Conditions which belong to a certain program to display them grouped with the same description and reward. If I'd add the description and reward to Program_Conditions it could be the same in many entries and thus it'll be redundant.

**Edit** based on Helio's answer:

```
Program OTM Program_Conditions
Program_Conditions_Groups OTM Program_Conditions
(Program OTM Program_Conditions_Groups)
```

A Program can kinda have many Program_Conditions_Groups through Program_Conditions. I need to access the Groups through a Program and also a single Group through a Program_Condition.

**Edit 2:** As of Walter Mitty's comment:

Let's assume there's this data in the three tables:

### Program

```
id    api_program_name
1     Program One
```

### Program_Conditions

```
id  program_id  program_conditions_group_id  description  reward
1   1           1                            Lorem        10
2   1           1                            Ipsum        10
3   1           1                            Dolor        20
```

### Program_Conditions_Groups

```
id  description  reward
1   Lorem Ipsum  10
```

Well, now I want to fetch all programs with all their groups. If I want to fetch a Program_Condition I also need to know which group it has.

I don't know if that design is right and if it's many-to-many even if a group can only belong to exactly one program. I don't feel comfortable with that design because I need to go through maybe 100 or even 1000 conditions, group them by group_id to get one single group.

So what do I have here? Am I even doing it right or is there a better design?

Comment: Can you describe the subject matter a little more clearly?  This will determine a table design that fits.

Comment: @WalterMitty: Please take a look at edit 2. Thanks.

Comment: Many-to-many relationships are discovered in the subject matter, and then reflected in the design.  You can't ask whether a given design correctly reflects the subject matter without describing the subject matter.  What problem were you trying to solve?

Comment: OK. I'm getting many programs and their conditions via API. Now it can be hundreds of conditions that kind of belong together but the description varies. I want to decide which of them belong together and save a description that matches every of the conditions. Instead of displaying all conditions with their own description to the user I now want to show him the groups only. This way I save him the time to look through hundreds of conditions with nearly the same topic.

Comment: If I got this last comment, your question isn't really about table design at all.  The table design is really determined by the API interface that's feeding you the data.  Your real question is, I guess, how to construct a query that gives the result you want,  given this table design as a starting place.  Or am I still misunderstanding you?

Comment: Oh no. I have the query and have no problems with query building at all. My only questions were if it's a good design or if there is a better one. And if it's many to many because you could think that table 2 is the pivot table. I just wasn't sure about this. It will turn to a big database where I have to join from the first over the second table to get the entries in the third. And this over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think I got it properly.

You mean that:

Programs OTM Programs_Conditions OTM Program_Conditions_Groups
or 
Programs OTM Programs_Conditions MTM Program_Conditions_Groups

OTM - one-to-many
MTM - many-to-many

if it's the first option, I would suggest you to use the fk in the "Program_Conditions_Groups" table, since it would be easier for you to retrieve the info.

Can you describe your scenario a little bit more?